# Formatting JSON containing single and double quotes within if statement in ARM template

Tags: json, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to specify the **storageProfile** property of a **Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine** resource in a conditional manner.

According to whether a certain parameter is set a certain JSON should be used.
According to the example at the following documentation page, this should be possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-logical#if

---

A reduced example which illustrates the issue:

```
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {},
  "properties": {
      "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "string"
  },
  "storageProfile": "[if(greater(parameters('myParameter', 0)), json('{\\\"dataDisks\\\": variables(\'myFirstVariable\')}'), json('{\\\"dataDisks\\\": variables(\'mySecondVariable\')}'))]"
```

The section I am struggling is the **storageProfile** property.

I get errors when submitting an ARM template in debug mode containing the above.

> cli.azure.cli.core.util : Failed to parse
>   test.json with exception:
>       Invalid \escape: line 275 column 110 (char 10373) Failed to parse 
>         test.json with exception:
>       Invalid \escape: line 275 column 110 (char 10373)

Character 110 at line 275 is the colon ":".

What should a correct request look like if the two JSON objects contain both double quotes and single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake for you, the error is not for the if statement, it's for the greater function. It should be like this:

```
greater(parameters('myParameter'), 0)
```

You can get more details about `greater` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-comparison#greater). And it seems the `json` function is also in the wrong format, the example is below:

```
json('{\"a\": \"b\"}')
```

For more details about the `json` function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#json).

All the error I can find out in the question that you posted is above. If there are any other errors, you need to give more details. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for your answer. That resolved the issue! 
I am running into a different issue now. 
`"dataDisks": "[if(greater(parameters('myParameter'), 0),json('[{\"name\": \"[concat(variables(''namingPrefix''), ''-database'')]\", \"diskSizeGB\": \"[int(parameters(''myParameter''))]\",\"lun\":0,\"createOption\":\"Empty\", \"caching\":\"None\"}]'),json('null'))]"`

Do you know why when submitting the above, I get the error **Could not convert string to integer: [int(parameters('myParameter'))]** ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Why not set the parameter type in the parameter block?

Comment: The parameter type is already set in the parameters block. "myParameter" is an *int*. Despite that, I still get this error.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness OK, if the parameter is already an int, then you just need to use the parameter like `parameter('myParameter')`.

Comment: In my JSON string, it looks like this `\"[parameters(''databaseVolumeSize'')]\"` I just tested and got the same error message regarding casting...

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Well, let's use the convert way, you set the parameter as a string type, then use the parameter like `int(parameter('myParameter'))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197539/discussion-between-unbearablelightness-and-charles-xu).

Answer (score 0):

There should be single backslash(**\**) in front of quotes. Try out below:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "apiVersion": "2019-03-01",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {

  },
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "string"
    },
    "storageProfile": "[if(greater(parameters('myParameter', 0)), json('{\"dataDisks\": variables(\'myFirstVariable\')}'), json('{\"dataDisks\": variables(\'mySecondVariable\')}'))]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still get the same error message upon submission though.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the complete ARM template, because the error states about escape characters and single backslash is the right way to escape quotes?